# Linq insert many to one rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I would like to insert 10 rows at once into a table that has a many to one relation with another table.

The MainTable.cs file appears as so:

```
public class MainTable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Customers Customers { get; set; }
    public string Attribute1 { get; set; }
    public string Attribute2 { get; set; }
}
```

And the Customers table appears as so:

```
public class Customers
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to add 10 rows into the MainTable with 10 different Attribute1 columns, while keeping the Customer the same. But when I try to add it as below, it does not give me the option to add repeated CustomerId:

```
    public void AddRecord(int customerId)
    {
        IEnumerable<Attributes> Attributes = GetAttributes();
        foreach (var attribute in Attributes)
        {
            _context.Add(new MainTable
            {
                 ***Customers.Id = customerId*** << Customers.Id doesn't exist.
                 Attribute1 = attribute
            });
        }
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

That's because the `MainTable` class (by the way, that's a terrible name for an entity class) doesn't have a customer ID field. It's expecting a complete `Customer` objects.

You can either pass the `Customer` object to the function:

```
public void AddRecord(Customer customer)
{
    IEnumerable<Attributes> Attributes = GetAttributes();
    foreach (var attribute in Attributes)
    {
        _context.Add(new MainTable
        {
             Customer = customer,
             Attribute1 = attribute
        });
    }
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Or you can get the `Customer` object from the ID inside the function:

```
public void AddRecord(int customerId)
{
    //First get the Customer object. This is an example, modify to your actual code
    Customer customer = GetCustomer(customerId);

    IEnumerable<Attributes> Attributes = GetAttributes();
    foreach (var attribute in Attributes)
    {
        _context.Add(new MainTable
        {
             Customer = customer,
             Attribute1 = attribute
        });
    }
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

You'll notice that I renamed the `MainTable.Customers` property to `Customer`. Using a plural noun is confusing. You Customer class is not a list, it's for a single entity, so rename it to singular noun `Customer` and do the same for the `MainTable.Customers` property.

If you actually want it to be a list, then change the property to:

```
public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
```

The `Customer` class should still be singular.

And then change the assignment line in the functions above to:

```
_context.Add(new MainTable
{
     Customers = new List<Customer>{ customer },
     Attribute1 = attribute
});
```

Comment: That was a lot of very helpful information. Thank you. At this point I'm getting the following error:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "PK_Customers". I am attempting to add multiple entries in the main table with the customer foreign key being the same and referring to an existing customer entry.

Comment: That means your `EntityFramwork` model is not setup properly, or you didn't get the `Customer` object properly. It's not recognizing that the `Customer` object is the same as the existing one and so it's trying to add it. Double check and fix your `EntityFramwork` model. It's hard to help you with that without seeing your `EntityFramwork` model .